# passing array contents as command inputs in bash

Tags: bash

I wish to pass a series of inputs to a single command, inside a bash script. The inputs can be somewhat long, so for readability, I would like to place them on separate lines. However, I seem to be running into issues with my double quotation marks?

this works:

```
command "python script1.py" "python script2.py"
```

What I have tried is then:

```
commandArr=(
"\"long input 1\""
"\"long input 2\""
)

command ${commandArr[@]}
```

but that just results in 'command' trying to execute on 'python' and then on 'script1.py', neither of which make sense.
So, how do I make sure that the whole 'line' is passed to 'command'?
I have also tried to just escape the newline:

```
command ^
"python script1.py"^
"python script2.py"^
```

but that did not help me either (this is to say that I am not particularly invested in the array-approach, I just want my command inputs on separate lines).

Comment: You need to wrap `${commandArr[@]}` in double quotes, and remove `\"`s from array elements.

Comment: if you make it an answer, I'll accept that :)

Comment: Don't have time, you post one and I'll upvote

Comment: Although it is perfectly reasonable to use an array, you can also accomplish your stated goal with that.  Unless you are going to re-use the array, or are building it dynamically, it might be better to simply insert newlines by ending the preceding line with a back-slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As oguz ismail commented on the question, the solution is to write:

```
commandArr=(
"long input 1"
"ong input 2"
)

command "${commandArr[@]}"
```